# Something that is more easily created than destroyed

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word used for describing a case where something is easier to create than to destroy. Which is the opposite of something that is harder to create than destroy (e.g creating a RC plane is hard but destroying it is easy).

Comment: Disorder is more easily created than destroyed.

Comment: Thermodynamics doesn't work that way. :-)

Comment: Sounds like a riddle.

Comment: Also, a bad first impression has this property.

Comment: I only know a phrase 'Some people would rather get even than get ahead'

Comment: Fundamental *could* work here, something that is fundamental or intrinsic must be there, and cannot *not* be there.

Comment: Rumor, disrepute, mess, and many variants of evil.

Comment: There's the "Pandora's Box" concept, that once something has been done it cannot easily be undone. *"Nuclear weapons can't be uninvented"* is a common example.

Comment: Could it be Habits?

Comment: @BiscuitBoy the question title should be: "...easier to create than..." OR "... never mind, someone corrected it.

Comment: It is Dream!!!!

Comment: A rumor. . . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider **nearly irrevocable** or **almost irreversible** (or "almost beyond recall").

> "irrevocable" definition: not able to be revoked, changed, or undone. *It mainly applies to decisions*.
>
> "irreversible" definition: that cannot be reversed or changed back. *It mainly applies to actions or permanent damages*.

Answer (score 0):

*What is a single word used for describing a case where something is easier to create than destroy:* (somewhat neologistically and definitely reeking of jargon but) one could perhaps say "contra-entropic."